# Setting Up Angular 6 along with Angular 1.5.8

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-hybrid

I have client which has product developed in Angular 1.5.8. The want to create a module of 3 pages in the same product with Angular 6. Is it possible to have such a setup?

Comment: It's possible, but certainly not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your reply William. The client is too stubborn on having such a setup. Can you guide me where to begin with?